# Same bootstrap Component on two modules

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, module

My app contains the following modules where I've the same component (AppComponent) as bootstrap.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MoreComponents
    ],
    imports: [BrowserModule, MoreModule],
    providers: [
        ModulesService, MoreServices,
    ],
    entryComponents: [SomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, BarTopComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

newApp.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MoreComponents
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, MoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ModulesService, MoreServices,  
    ],
    entryComponents: [SomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, OtherComponent],
})
export class AppNewModule { }
```

The right module is loaded according to a parameter. Something like

main.ts

```
if (Utils.someParameter()) {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then((module: { injector: { get: (arg0: any) => { (): any; new(): any; components: any[]; }; }; }) => {

    }).catch(err => console.error(err));

} else {
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppNewModule).then((module: { injector: { get: (arg0: any) => { (): any; new(): any; components: any[]; }; }; }) => {
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

This lead me to the error "AppComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules".

What's the best way to deal with this?

I created a share module like this:

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        // Components
        AppComponent,
    ],
    exports: [
        AppComponent
    ],

})
export class SharedModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MoreComponents
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule, BrowserModule, MoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ModulesService, MoreServices,
    ],
    entryComponents: [SomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent, ApplicationBarTopComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

newApp.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MoreComponents
    ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule, BrowserModule, MoreModule
    ],
    providers: [
        ModulesService, MoreServices,  
    ],
    entryComponents: [SomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppNewModule , OtherComponent],
})
export class AppNewModule { }
```

but I still have the same issue.

I also try to create a new NewAppComponent containing the same code as AppComponent but this also doesn't work because on controllers I'm injecting the AppComponent.

For instance:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'someSelector',
    templateUrl: './random.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RandomComponent  {
    
    constructor(public application: AppComponent) {
    }
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: I think you should move the main/shareable logic to a single `AppComponent` and to use routes to evaluate which specialized one to use of the current two. Once Loaded in a single angular app, you cannot unload a Component. So you would be stuck on this error with the component loaded by two models

Comment: I don't have the budget to it a so massive update but thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure that note the clear way to do it but I found a solution. I now have two bootstrap controllers  (AppController and AppNewController) and on the others controller

```
@Component({
    selector: 'someSelector',
    templateUrl: './random.component.html',
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class RandomComponent  {
    public app: any;
    
    constructor(@Optional() public tempApp: AppComponent,
                @Optional() public tmpNewApp: AppNewComponent) 
    {
        if (someConditions) {
            this.app = tempApp;
        } else {
            this.app = tmpNewApp;
        }
    }}
```